# Shell Script to for remote copy and then processing the file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, hp-ux

The below script works fine. But when I try to add a command to remote copy and then assign  the variable FILENAME with the file received from the remote copy, the while loop doesn't work. I am quite new to scripting so I'm not able to find out what I'm missing. Please help!

```
#!/bin/sh
#SCRIPT:  File processing
#PURPOSE: Process a file line by line with redirected while-read loop.
SSID=$1
ASID=$2
##rcp server0:/oracle/v11//dbs/${SSID}_ora_dir.lst /users/global/rahul/${ASID}_clone_dir.lst
##FILENAME=/users/global/rahul/${ASID}_clone_dir.lst
count=0
while read LINE
do
echo $LINE | sed -e "s/${SSID}/${ASID}/g"
count=`expr $count + 1`
done < $FILENAME
echo -e "\nTotal $count Lines read"
grep -v -e "pattern3" -e "pattern5" -e "pattern6" -e "pattern7" -e "pattern8" -e "pattern9" -e "pattern10" -e "pattern11" -e "
pattern12" ${ASID}_.lst > test_remote.test
```

Comment: i don't understand this line, what is doing: done < $FILENAME

Comment: It's making the "while" loop read from $FILENAME rather than stdin

Comment: btw: the "count=0" line is either buggy or a typo -- do you have a command called "enter" which takes "code" and "here" as arguments? :)

Comment: @loreb that was a typo

Answer (score 0):

When you say, "the while loop doesn't work", if you get an error message you should include that in your question to give us a clue.

Are you sure the `rcp` command is successful? The file `/users/global/rahul/${ASID}_clone_dir.lst` exists after the `rcp` is completed?

Btw your `while` loop is inefficient. This should be equivalent:

```
sed -e "s/${SSID}/${ASID}/g" < "$FILENAME"
count=$(wc -l "$FILENAME" | awk '{print $1}')
echo -e "\nTotal $count Lines read"
```